# interpreting bytes as ushorts in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I need to interpret 16 bytes received over a TCP socket as 8 ushorts.

This line correctly receives the data (the 16-bit values of 8 a-d converters), and I can access each byte as an index into a byte array:

```
vals = bytearray(s.recv(16))
```

And I could create 8 variables and decode each:

```
ad1 = (ord(vals[0]) * 256)+ord(vals[1])
```

But it would be more elegant if I could recast this array as 8 ushorts.

I have tried many variations of struct.unpack, with just as many syntax errors. My background is in C, so I would ordinarily use a union or recast a byte pointer, but...

can anyone point me in the right direction?  thanks, and my apologies if this has been asked before.

#

here is the full monty:

```
import socket,struct,time
import xrlib

def readADx(socket,a2dnumber):
# a2dnumber 1 - 8
if a2dnumber < 1 or a2dnumber > 8:
      return 0
a2d = a2dnumber + 0x9D
tdata = struct.pack('BB',0xFE,a2d)
s.send(tdata)
val = ord(s.recv(1)) * 256
val = val + ord(s.recv(1))
return val
#
# define TCP client socket:
# 
IPADDR = '192.168.99.9'
PORTNUM = 2101
s =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IPADDR,PORTNUM))
tdata = struct.pack('BB',0xFE,0xA7)
s.send(tdata)
#
# the problem:
#
vals = bytearray(s.recv(16))
adv = struct.unpack('8H',vals)
#
# get the true values for A/D 7 and 8:
#
ad8 = readADx(s,8);
ad7 = readADx(s,7);
s.close()

print("%04X %04X %04X %04X %04X %04X %04X %04X"%adv[0],adv[1],adv[2],adv[3],adv[4],adv[5],adv[6],adv[7]))
print("AD8: %d"%(ad8));
print("AD7: %d"%(ad7));
print("adv[7]: %d"%(adv[7]));
print("adv[6]: %d"%(adv[6]));
```

running this gives this error:

```
 struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 16
```

this is the error I would invariably get, with different argument lengths.

this code works:

```
 adv = struct.unpack('8H',s.recv(16))
```

but the byte order of each reading (adv[x]) is reversed. I found socket.ntohs() to fix this.

Still not sure why the struct.unpack would not work with the bytearray arg...

Comment: struct.unpack is the right way.

Comment: If you showed us what you tried and what errors you got we could probably point out where you went wrong.

Comment: `vals` is a bytearray, so `vals[0]` is already an `int`. Taking `ord` of an `int` is an error too.

Answer (score 3):

(transforming a comment to an answer)

```
ad1 = struct.unpack('8H', vals)
```